# Http get exception Target host must not be null on ICS

Tags: java, android, google-api, http-get

I am getting this exception on ICS, while on 2.2 it is running fine.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=32.0692342,34.7952296&sensor=true
```

Here is my code:

```
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URLEncoder.encode(requestUrl, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response;
        response = mHttpClient.execute(request);
```

Comment: can you post requestUrl also? It seems it is not in proper format.

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=32.0692342,34.7952296&sensor=true

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `URLEncoder.encode` call, it is not needed

It is needed to encode the url parameters, for example:

```
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+URLEncoder.encode("32.0692342,34.7952296")+"&sensor="+URLEncoder.encode("true")
```

Comment: But what if I need to encode the url before?
10-17 16:29:53.235: W/System.err(18170): java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 58: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=, בדיקה,&sensor=true

Comment: You only need to encode the URL parameters, not the whole url